# Add a custom sound in Windows Ce 5.0 visual studio 2005

Tags: c#, embedded, device

I am trying to find out the information of how could be able to put a custom sound file into the device and playing from my application which is windows ce 5.0 in visual studio 2005.

As I know that there is a possibility to make a sound of "Beep" by "coredll.dll".
The thing is that make a custom one and play that one.

Any possbility ?

Thank for advice

Answer (score 0):

First verify the device plays audio correctly.
Import the `System.Media` namespace and play a sound with a button.

```
SystemSounds.Asterisk.Play();
```

If this is working, you can try a .wav file. You can copy a file from the `C:\Windows\Media` directory on your computer, to the device.

```
SoundPlayer sound_player = new SoundPlayer(@"\DiskOnChip\tada.wav");
sound_player.Play();
```

This succesfully plays the file.

This requires .NET CF 3.5, it will not work in .NET CF 2.0

Comment: I cannot find the namespace of "System.Media". As my researching is that in device application we are not able to add the dll as a reference.  Any idea?

Comment: It seems *System.Media* is not available in .NET CF 2.0, I had previously changed the target platform of the existing project after testing in 3.5, but creating a new project with 2.0 from the start gives different results. Are you able to deploy .NET CF 3.5 ?